# How to sync git on ubuntu with existing github projects?

Tags: linux, git, github

I used mac github client to push my codes to my github account. On my Ubuntu linux computer I wan't to connect to github using the terminal so that it will automatically sync will all my projects on github. How would I do it? All the online help I have bumped in to so far only show how to clone an exiting git repository not how to connect to my github account and sync it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git, the revision control system, doesn't know anything about Github, a website that keeps track of and hosts your git repositories for you.  The concept of a Github account is totally alien to git, so you'll never be able to, say, browse all of the projects you own on Github with a `git` command.  git only works on the level of individual repositories.

Github also provides a graphical client that handles both the git level stuff and the Github level stuff -- it understands what a Github account is, and will log in for you and display all of the repos associated with the account.  It's also a fully featured git client that does a lot of work on the level of individual repos for you.  However, this graphical client is currently only available for Windows and OS X, and is not available for Linux.

My own workflow on Linux is to use the github.com website plus the command-line `git` tool.  To bridge the gap between Github and git, you need to `git clone` individual repos.  Aside from that, you can do Github administrative tasks on the website, and you can work with individual repos with `git` on the command line.

If you don't like this work flow, you need to look at graphical git clients for Linux.  I'm not sure if any exist that will do both git-level stuff and also interface with Github specifically and understand the idea of a Github account.

You could also theoretically try to run the Windows client in `wine` on Linux, but I would not recommend this approach except as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. Its a shame github doesn't have a Linux client. I will do it the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

First I don't know a program that automatically sync all my  github repositories.

1. First you have to install git (if it has not been done already) [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-12-04)
2. Than you should generate a rsa:key to be able to '**push**' your repositories to github.
   You can generate a rsa_key by following this [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) ***notes*** `ssh-add id_rsa` should be `ssh-add id_rsa.pub`  ....also you can name id_rsa as anything you want: like `bran_rsa_key`
3. You should post or add your rsa_key to git hub at this [address](https://github.com/settings/ssh). If you go to that link you will see that you already have some key for your Mac but nothing for your Ubuntu.
4. After installation you could install [ungit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkBVAi3oKvo) if you're not that familliar with git

Comment: Thanks for the step by step. I already know how to setup git I wanted to know if I could sync all my repos on my github account instead of individually cloning repos. It seems like I can't.